# Using @property on a Base Class' Attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties

I have a base class which is not accessible, and I want to use one of its attributes as a `@property`. I need mainly the `.setter` because there are some validations I need to make on the value. I can not setup the property with a different name than the attribute. Below is basically what I want to do. Is there any way to do this?

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = ""

class Child(Base):
    @property
    def var(self):
        #getter

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        #super.var = value
```

Comment: @chepner I think `Base` is a given, it can't be redefined. But why do you think the `__init__` method doesn't have access to the instance?

Comment: I'm not saying `Base` should be redefined; I'm saying the question should include an actual working example of the base class. (The current definition is from an edit made by someone other than the OP.)

Comment: @chepner This is more or less what I wanted to do. I have base class and it has attribute . I can't edit the base class so in the extended class and I wanted to add the validations and other things before we assign the value to the attribute of the base class. I thought 'property' can be used here but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing with inheritance is that once you defined a `@property` (and a `.setter`) with the same name as a parent's attribute, the `__init__` of the parent will already call that `@property`'s setter! (or if it doesn't have a setter, an `AttributeError` will be raised)

So basically all you have to do is set an internal name for the `Child`'s attribute:

```py
class Child(Base):
    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        self._var = value
```

---

Now, we can use the following code to follow the execution:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("In Base's __init__ - setting `var` with 'default'")
        self.var = "default"

class Child(Base):
    @property
    def var(self):
        print("In Child's `var` @property getter - getting `_var`")
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        print(f"In Child's `var` setter - setting `_var` with {value}")
        if isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError("Can't set var to an int!")
        self._var = value

c = Child()
print("-")
print(f"c.__dict__ - {c.__dict__}")
print("-")
print(f"c.var - {c.var}")
print("-")
c.var = "new"
print("-")
print(f"new c.var - {c.var}")
print("-")
c.var = 3
```

And the result will be:

```
In Base's __init__ - setting `var` with 'default'
In Child's `var` setter - setting `_var` with default
-
c.__dict__ - {'_var': 'default'}
-
In Child's `var` @property getter - getting `_var`
c.var - default
-
In Child's `var` setter - setting `_var` with new
-
In Child's `var` @property getter - getting `_var`
new c.var - new
-
In Child's `var` setter - setting `_var` with 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tomer/Desktop/python/tests.py", line 29, in <module>
    c.var = 3
  File "C:/Users/tomer/Desktop/python/tests.py", line 16, in var
    raise TypeError("Can't set var to an int!")
TypeError: Can't set var to an int!
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was looking for. One more question, is there any way we can avoid the extra variable of child. So when we set, it just runs the validation against values.

Comment: You can run the validations anyway (as I did as an example with the int value). If you try to use the same name you will get an infinite recurssion loop as the assignment will call the setter which assigns and so on and so on. Anyway, it is not really an *extra* variable, as you can see from the print of `__dict__`, it actually "replaces" the original `var`

Comment: My bad, Didn't notice that. I think, I can not remove the assignment thing, else getter will not work.

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? I don't understand

Comment: If you remove the assignment, what will the `setter` set? There will be nothing to get in the first place (apart from that the getter will not work... @VishalSoni

Comment: Sorry as I was not clear, What I wanted is to add some validations and other things before we assign value to the attribute present in the base class. So your answer is correct and it works,  I was asking - is it possible to keep only the code and remove the assignment?

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't follow. How would you update/set a value, if you don't assign anything? If I understand you, you need to understand that once you define a `.setter` for a property, that means that whenever you write `obj.var = value` that setter will be called, **and that's it!** Nothing in the parent class will happen. So you will have to assign the value because nothing is going to be assigned elsewhere

Comment: Got it @Tomerikoo. I mixed up two things together. So the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure that I have understood the question properly. But what I got is. You can directly use init function and define the attribute in it. if you want the attribute to be private. you can set value those attribute using getters and setters method

like:-

```
class Base():
    self.var = ""

class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self):
       var=super().var
```

Comment: This doesn't seem related to defining a property.